# When Activity.attach() will be called?

Tags: android, android-activity, window

When I study the Activity's create process and I found that var mWindow was initialized in Actviity'attach().like this

```
final void attach(Context context, ActivityThread aThread,
        Instrumentation instr, IBinder token, int ident,
        Application application, Intent intent, ActivityInfo info,
        CharSequence title, Activity parent, String id,
        NonConfigurationInstances lastNonConfigurationInstances,
        Configuration config, String referrer, IVoiceInteractor voiceInteractor) {
    attachBaseContext(context);

    mFragments.attachActivity(this, mContainer, null);

    mWindow = PolicyManager.makeNewWindow(this);
    mWindow.setCallback(this);
    mWindow.setOnWindowDismissedCallback(this);
    mWindow.getLayoutInflater().setPrivateFactory(this);
    ...
}
```

But I don't know when this method will be called.
anyone who can answer me?
thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's called in the function named `performLaunchActivity` of class `ActivityThread`, before `onCreate`.

Comment: thank you..  and do you know when will var in PhoneWindow.java that named mDecor be attached with ViewRootImp?

Comment: I got it that happened in the method named handleResumeActivity of class ActivityThread.Thank you a lot.